# How to return nearby lines when using "findstr" command in Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

> How to return nearby lines when using "findstr" command in Windows Command Prompt?

I find the `findstr` useful when searching for lines in files.

However, I want to use it like `grep -C <n>`, to return nearby lines of the matched line.

How can I do this in Windows?

Comment: I'd use PowerShell instead and it's `Select-String` with the -context parameter.

Comment: Neither `findstr` nor `find` support context. You can wrap the `Select-String` Powershell function in a batch file so that it can give you context or just use [grep on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678853/is-there-any-way-to-use-unix-grep-commands-on-windows-operating-system).